# ListView stop scrolling does not work

Tags: android, android-listview

I've made custom adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() then data updates. But after call notifyDataSetChanged() I can't stop scrolling of listview by touch.
I looked at android's source code and found that code in file AbsListView.class (which is parent of ListView)

```
if (!mDataChanged) { ... }
```

There is a code to stop scrolling ListView on touch event.

So then we call notifyDataSetChanged() we set mDataChanged in true and so can't stop scrolling.

Could u help me to find out how to enable stop scrolling after data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are reading data while the ListView calls `getItem` method. Using an asynchronous data loading (Handler) could be a better idea. You may find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566101/how-to-fix-notifydatasetchanged-listview-problems-in-dynamic-adapter-wrapper-and).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the scroll position of your `ListView` and scroll the list till that scroll amount again after the list is refreshed.

To do so, call this method before `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
private void saveListScrollPosition() {
        // save index and top position
        index = _listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View view = _listview.getChildAt(0);
        top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
    }
```

And after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

write the following line -

```
    // restore list scroll position
    _listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

where, `index`, `top` and `_listview` are all fields accessible to any method.

Comment: Why do u think it should help? Because in code android checks if (!mDataChanged) { ... } (however I've tryid your code and it did not help)